# Acer Aspire Can't boot from CD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, acer-aspire, cd

My harddrive is slowing down more and more, so I decided to install a new harddrive.

I have the installation discs for the default software for the computer, but something is troubling me.

I have set the bios type to legacy and the secure boot to false. But when I try to boot, I get this:

[image: BIOS PXE boot failure]

It can't read the cd, and I have no idea how to fix this error.

I should mention that Windows 8 can read the image just fine.

Comment: Check that the cable to the hard drive is connected properly. Are you trying to do a PXE boot?

Comment: No, boot from the CD drive using the Recovery Discs

Comment: That's for macbook, not PC

Comment: Sorry pasted the wrong link. ===> Here's the new [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xeLLmxzDdY)

Comment: still no help, the problem isn't the harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your BIOS settings - I suspect you've somehow gotten CD out of your list of bootable devices. The "Media Error" you're seeing is a PXE (network) boot error, and has nothing to do with your CD.

There is usually a magic key sequence flashed on the screen that will tell you how to get in to the BIOS menus (or try ESC, DEL, F8, F10).

Comment: It could also be, on an older PC or one with an external CD/DVD drive, that the drivers are not available at boot time, in which case it may be easier to boot from a USB flash drive.